# how to set the inital rotation of an echarts-gl chart?

Tags: echarts

Currently, a set of data points I have look like this:

[image: Normal]

I wish to have it looking like this, which is the z-axis rotated 180 degrees:

[image: After]

Which variable do I have to set in echarts?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grid3D: {
    viewControl: { alpha: 15,
                   beta: -25
    }
}
```